# 2D array slicing

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

due to the fact that now there is a possibility to slice array with sneaky peaky way like `arr[1..4]` I wanted to slice 2D array.

Consider the following:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[4][]
{
    new int[] {1,2,3,4 },
    new int[] {5,6,7,8 },
    new int[] {9,10,11,12 },
    new int[] {13,14,15,16 }
};

foreach (var item in matrix[0..2][0..2].SelectMany(x => x))
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
}
// output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

foreach (var item in matrix[0..3][0..2].SelectMany(x => x))
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
}
// output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8


foreach (var item in matrix[0..1][0..2].SelectMany(x => x))
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
}
// Error : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values
```

I expect first output to be `1 2 5 6`, second `1 2 5 6 9 10` and third `1 2`.

How can I do it in a "slicing manner" to achieve expected output?

P.S. Is it me or this is counter-intuitive behavior.

Comment: Do you understand what it *is* doing?

Comment: FYI that's not a 2D array.  That's a jagged array, or array of arrays.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't want to be rude but if I would understand it then I wouldn't have asked that question. Honestly I thought that it would work in the way python is slicing. Well I learnt something today. Thanks :)

Comment: @juharr Thanks. That forced me to check 2D array and... it's not possible to call `matrix[0..2, 0..2]` :D. I'm still examining why

Comment: @Pawel: For example, `byte a = 1, b = 2, c; c = a + b;` causes a compile error in C#.  Even though I know what leads to the error, I might come looking for a workaround and also ask whether other people consider the current behavior to be counterintuitive.

Comment: @Pawel That's because a 2 or more dimensional array is really just a normal array where the indexes of the dimensions are combined to locate the "real" index.  So there's no way to slice a square or cube out of it without creating a new array to hold the values.

Comment: @juharr: Such slicing could be supported, but the result would have to be a fancy proxy collection.  There wouldn't be contiguity and you couldn't access it as a raw Span.

Comment: @BenVoigt My apologies then :)

Comment: @juharr That's a shame. I'm completely fine with making a array copy when slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var slice = matrix[0..2][0..2];
```

You are actually slicing your array *twice*. It's equivalent to writing:

```
var temp = matrix[0..2];
var slice = temp[0..2];
```

Which in this case, makes the second slice redundant. You can confirm this by writing:

```
var slice = matrix[0..2][0..3]
```

In this case, the second slice will throw an exception because it is larger than the first slice.

What I think you are trying to do is this:

```
foreach (var item in matrix[0..2].SelectMany(x => x[0..2]))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one will work... you need to slice each row in the subset generated from the first slice, and not the collection of rows itself:

```
matrix[0..3].SelectMany(r => r[0..2])
```

A slice index acts on a collection and produces a new collection, unlike scalar indexing which returns one element of the collection.  As a result, indexing again now acts on the slice and not on an element inside the slice... so you need to use select to apply to each element.